# listener sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android

I've a problem with this code. I want keep preferences values in my app but I've problem with the listener. Does not work, its does not save new values. Any idea about error(s)?

EDIT: `onResume()` works because when I open an activity on my app and close it, the value of sharepreferences is correct. Dialogs and activities does not keep values.

```
public void onCreate(){
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
          listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
              public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String listpref) {
                    if(!preferencesChanged)preferenze();

            }
              };
      sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

There are some buttons and other info activities called by intents.
A TextView that show a value from array and nothing.

```
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        sp.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);

protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String listpref) {
        preferencesChanged = true;
                }
        };
        sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);

protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        if(preferencesChanged){
            //Update the app
            preferenze();
        }


public void preferenze()
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

        CheckboxPreference = prefs.getBoolean("checkboxPref", true);
        ListPreference = prefs.getString("listpref", "");
```

Others variables and most if/else.

Preferences.xml:

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String listpref) {
```

Comment: where you are calling `onCreate()` method ?

Comment: Was at the end of code. I just updated.

Comment: can u plz edit whole class code then it's very help full in solving issue

Comment: 4000 lines. I try to modify the code

Comment: I'm at work, firewall blocks pastebin.com, sorry.

Comment: I added Preferences.java

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings); SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this); }
```

I think, you are missing registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener